# How to set background color of UIPickerView using UIAppearance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am using the following line of code to change the background color of `UIPickerView` throughout my app as it is for a theme in the app. This changes nothing.

```
 [[UIPickerView appearance] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
```

I also tried the following line but that give a weird shaded background that looks terrible.

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UIPickerView class]]] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Here is an image of what the above line shows:
[image]

I want the background color to be one solid color.

The question is, how can I change the background color of `UIPickerView` in the whole app using `UIAppearance`?

Comment: where do you put this code : `[[UIPickerView appearance] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my Knowledge UIPicker does not conforms to UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR for UIAppereance ..

```
[pickerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

OR You Might want use..

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Above two are the solutions i would prefer to change Picker Appearance..There although an other way to set an image, but i won't suggest to use that.

Its up to you NOW..

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.

Comment: i don't think that UIPickerview conforms to UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. Thats why i wrote this answer

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0:

I managed to solve it using the method `func numberOfComponents (in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int` like this:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackDark
    return 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also trying to update backgroundColor property at init but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the code Please have a look,

```
 self.pickerView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
```

This code is working for me fine.

In case It does not work for you,
I'll recommend another way to change the background color.

Drag a UIView and have a the same size as UIPickerView is having,
also select color of UIView color (the color that you want as backgound).
Drag and Drop you picker view inside that View.

Please let me know, It's working or not.

Comment: The question says "using UIAppearance". This answer is wrong.